# What earliest sources mention reincarnation explicitly?

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, reincarnation

Where is an explicit reference to reincarnation first mentioned in Jewish literature?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you believe it was written by Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai, the Zohar, parashat Mishpatim is likely the earliest explicit source concerning gilgulim.

Comment: And if it was not written by Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai?